# How to update count with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My events model code is like this:

```
def current_date
    Date.today
end

def self.count_past(current_date = Date.today)
   Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date < ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
end

def self.count_upcoming(current_date = Date.today)
   Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date > ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
   #this statment is equivalent to
   #select * from events where start_date > current_date order by start_date
end

def self.count_today(current_date = Date.today)
    Event.count :all, :conditions => ['start_date = ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date'
end
```

My code of `view(index file)` is like this:

```
%li
  %a.tt-top-center{:title => "Total Events", :href => events_path}#{Event.all.size}
  %span Total events
%li
  %a.blue.tt-top-center{:title => "Today's Events", :href => events_path(:view => "today")}#{Event.count_today}
  %span Today's Events
%li
  %a.green.tt-top-center{:title => "Past Events", :href => events_path(:view => "past")}#{Event.count_past}
  %span Past Events
%li
  %a.tt-top-center{:title => "Upcoming Events", :href => events_path(:view => "upcoming")}#{Event.count_upcoming} 
  %span Upcoming Events
```

My `controllers` code is like this:
  def index

```
case params[:view]
when 'past'
  @events  = Event.find (:all, :conditions => ['start_date < ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date')
when 'today'
  @events = Event.find (:all, :conditions => ['(start_date  = current_date)'], :order => 'start_date ')
when 'upcoming'
  @events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['start_date > ?', current_date], :order => 'start_date')
else
  @events = Event.all
end
  end
```

Please tell me how can I use `ajax` when I click on the respective links `today's events`, `total events` etc. and how can I update the event count using `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:remote => true` for a AJAX call.

For this you will need to add a `respond_to` block in your controller method(s) that respond to a js (`format.js`).  More information about the [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to).

This would then execute the corresponding `.js.erb` file in your views.  From there you can update the view using `javascript` (and update the event count).

A good starting point about using [AJAX on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html).

Comment: I updated my controller like this: respond_to do |format|
       format.html{redirect_to @event}           # new.html.erb
       format.js   { render :partial => 'show', :locals => {:event => @event} }
     end   I also made a partial of show and called it from controller. But it is giving me some error like template missing. Plz tell me what to do

Comment: @SnehaKachroo Can you update the controller and other (relevant) code in your question?  Also, what is the exact error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error and the item is successfully getting deleted by ajax but my count is not updated . Only after I refresh my page manually it is showing the exact count. Please tell me how to update with ajax

Comment: Can I see what your `.js.erb` file looks like?  Also, in any of the code that you posted, I don't see anything related to the `deletion` of and event?